# Can't resolve 'three' in three-gltf-loader

Tags: vue.js, three.js

This is the first time that I cannot find an answer and have to write here. I am trying a three.js project with Vue.js. I have this error:

> Failed to compile.
> ./node_modules/three-gltf-loader/index.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three' in 'C:\Users\Skunk\Documents\dolfin\dolfin\node_modules\three-gltf-loader'

My code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three-js';
import GLTFLoader from 'three-gltf-loader';
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  mounted(){
    let scene = new THREE.Scene( );
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function( )
    {
      let width = window.innerWidth;
      let height = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.setSize( width, height);
      camera.aspect = width / height;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix( );
    } );
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();


// Load a glTF resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'models/dol.gltf',
        // called when the resource is loaded
        function ( gltf ) {

          scene.add( gltf.scene );

          gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
          gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
          gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
          gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
          gltf.asset; // Object

        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {

          console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        }
    );

    camera.position.z = 3;

    //let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.8);
    // scene.add( ambientLight );

    // game logic
    let update = function ( )
    {};

    // draw scene
    let render = function( )
    {
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };

    // run game loop
    let GameLoop = function( )
    {
      requestAnimationFrame( GameLoop );
      update( );
      render( );
    };

    GameLoop( );
  }
}
```

Am I using pieces of code that are not compatible?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you should not be using the ["three-js" node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-js). This is a really outdated version of Three that got stuck on `r79` and hasn't been updated in 4 years. Instead, you should be using the official ["three" node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three), which is the legitimate library, and is currently on `r124`.

Second, just import the GLTF loader from the "three/examples" folder as demonstrated [in the GLTF examples](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf), instead of installing a whole new module.

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Error appeared to me and this command fixed it for me,

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps three --force
```